# Check referrer and find the href that leads to it, then trigger a click with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working on a WP single page portfolio that loads post content with AJAX. I read that WP doesn't need `#!` URLs to make it crawlable by Googlebot. If I understand it correctly, since Googlebot won't interpret ajax, it will just follow the link and index the article page.

So I removed `#!` from my URLs and when a post is opened I update them with `.pushState`.
It's working fine, but if I hit F5 or if I try to load a specific URL (not the home) I fall into the page of the post (single.php).

To prevent it, I added a javascript redirection in single.php that leads users to the homepage. Then I need to open the content of the article on the homepage.

Here is the address of my site: `http://www.youpiemonday.com/` (the redirection isn't online yet).

How can I tell the browser "if you're coming from this page (the referrer), trigger a click on the thumbnail which href is corresponding" (the click will load the content)?

I'm digging around this but I have no idea how to target the thumbnail correctly...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $referer = document.referrer; // where we come from
    $LinktoRef = $('.ProjectWrap').find("a").href; // the href in the thumbnail

    console.debug($LinktoRef); // still undefined...

        if ( $LinktoRef == $referer ){
            find("a").trigger('click');
        }
</script>
```

Here is what the html markup looks like:

```
<div id="portfolio-list">

    <div class="ProjectWrap">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="contentProject">
                    <h4 class="ProjectTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                </div>
           </a>
    </div>

    <div class="ProjectWrap">//same as above</div>
    <div class="ProjectWrap">//same as above</div>
    // and the list goes on...

</div>
```

I'm not really a programmer so any help would be very appreciated. And if you can comment your code, that would be invaluable to me.

Comment: Just btw, Googlebot *does* understand ajax.

Comment: You should not use the referer for things like that (actually, you should not use it at all). If you have an URL for a single post, then loading that URL should *not* redirect to some other page.

Comment: yeah but there is a lot of trick to make it crawlable and my server won't allow headless browser installing... I want to keep the user on a single page website. Only google is supposed to see those other pages.

Comment: If you don't want your users to see that pages, don't show them their URLs with `pushState`.

Comment: I want them to be able to load those URL and see its content, but on the homepage, not on the single page.

Comment: Trigger clicks on anchor elements for redirection is a new idea to me. Ugly and nice at the same time :) Nice to know, what not to do.

Comment: Then ajax-load the homepage around the single content, instead of redirecting and loading what was already there.

Comment: @feeela Maybe it isn't clear, I'm redirecting only if you load a specific Url. If you land on the home, you'll never be redirected.

Comment: @wyem Try to eliminate that additional redirect, as the client loads a website, just get redirected. Try to use server side redirects in any case.

Comment: how can I do that? I don't understand what is wrong with how I proceed.

Comment: Are server side redirections better bandwidth-wise?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are probably trying to reference the element before it is rendered on the page. Use document ready or window onload and reference the link there.

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem. Maybe I'm targeting thumbnails the wrong way... Could you look at the site and compare with my script? How would you proceed to find a specific href in those thumbnails?